# How to get data type length(max) of a SQL Table in SQL Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I tried get  result of "Script Table as Create To Query" by a SQL Query for my tables.

It is like Right click on table->Script Table as ->Create To->Query on SQL Management Studio

I have this query :

```
                declare @vsSQL varchar(8000)
                declare @vsTableName varchar(50)
                select @vsTableName = 'dbo.TableName'
                select @vsSQL = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @vsTableName + char(10) + '(' + char(10)
                select @vsSQL = @vsSQL + ' ' + sc.Name + ' ' +
                st.Name +
                case when st.Name in 
               ('varchar','varchar','char','nchar','nvarchar') then '(' + 
                cast(sc.Length as varchar) + ') ' else ' ' end +
                case when sc.IsNullable = 1 then 'NULL' else 'NOT NULL' end + ',' + char(10)
                from sysobjects so
                join syscolumns sc on sc.id = so.id
                join systypes st on st.xusertype = sc.xusertype
                where so.name = @vsTableName
                order by
                sc.ColID
                select substring(@vsSQL,1,len(@vsSQL) - 2) + char(10) + ')
```

Result of Query :

```
CREATE TABLE TableName (
                        Id int NOT NULL,  
                        Name nvarchar(-1) NULL,
                        Code int NULL,
                        Adress nvarchar (200) NOT NULL 
                        )
```

But my query can not take nvarchar(max).It show nvarchar(-1)

How can change my query for to be like this :

Chage nvarchar(-1) to nvarchar(max)

```
CREATE TABLE TableName (
                        Id int NOT NULL,  
                        Name nvarchar(max) NULL,  
                        Code int NULL,
                        Adress nvarchar (200) NOT NULL
                        )
```

Comment: I'm curious why your create table script looks like a stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this line in the code:

```
cast(sc.Length as varchar)
```

Change it to:

```
(case when sc.length < 0 then 'max' else cast(sc.Length as varchar(255)) end)
```

Notice that I also added a length parameter to `varchar()`.  *Always* specify a length when you use the type.  When the default length is not long enough for what you are doing, finding the problem is really hard.

Comment: Sir thank you so much.I have a small problem.I tried add to ')' but I failed.http://pastebin.com/Z8URfxTD

Comment: Solved by your answer.Thank you again.